# How can I map the Esc key to the Caps Lock key?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I would like to remap the Esc key to the Caps Lock key. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Before marking as duplicate, read well the question. There are already a lot of other questions asking the **opposite** thing to what I want to achieve.

Comment: So what have you tried so far, where did it not work as expected? And I assume we are talking about a Mac with a physical Esc key, not a Touchbar.

Comment: At the **very least** edit your question to include the macOS version

Comment: Also: Please edit the first question you've asked to add all the things you got asked to clarify: version of macOS, physical key, what you have tried etc. The question will then get put into the review queue for reopenings automatically